# Is stomach acid an emulsion?

Tags: stomach, oil, digestion

It occurred to me that oils float on water, and the stomach is always full of aqueous solution. The stomach empties at the bottom, meaning that oils would only ever pass out of the stomach when it is clear of water, which it never is. Assuming stomach acid is not an emulsion, oils would slowly build up above the water, which would negatively affect health if they never drain. Assuming it is an emulsion, the oils can drain with the aqueous components, and that is that.

So does the stomach have some special way of draining oils, or is stomach acid actually an emulsion. In either case, how?

Answer (score 7):

Well, you eat a number of things - protein, carbohydrates, fats, water, alcohol (at times), etc.  Digestion begins in the mouth.The stomach muscles contract periodically, churning food to enhance digestion, breaking it into tiny particles called "chyme", which can indeed be an emulsion. The stomach doesn't act as a beaker; it has input and shakes things up.

The chyme is passed into the duodenum, where digestion takes place, and continues through the small intestines. Once the food reaches the large intestion, it is pretty much digested, and water reabsorption takes place.

<sub>[Surprising Facts About Your Stomach](http://www.webmd.com/women/features/stomach-problems)</sub>